# Segments for variables in C programs?

Tags: c, memory

Where are each expression stored in memory? 
Where would be constant variables stored?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int a = 0;                   // initialized data segment
char arr[10] = "hello";      // initialized data segment
const int k = -1;            //
int* gptr = &a;              //

int main()
{
    const int m = 31;        //
    int n;                   //
    int* ptr;                //
    ptr = malloc(1024);      // heap segment

    char* ptr2 = &arr;       //

    for(n = 0; n<1024; ++n)  //
        printf("%d ", n);    //
}
```

Comment: Only the OS kernel knows where they are stored. Or perhaps do you executable file segments like .data and .rodata? Or do you mean whose in the heap and whose in the stack?

Comment: One normally talks about [storage duration](http://iso-9899.info/wiki/Storage_Duration). Where stuff is actually stored is at least somewhat implementation-specific.

Comment: In C, `k` is just a restricted global variable (it can't be modified legitimately).  It might be stored in a read-only segment, but more likely won't be; it will probably be in the same segment as other global variables.

Comment: Wouldn't k be optimized away by the compiler?

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon yes, `k` might be optimized away because it's not used in the code here, but this depends on the compiler and on the compilation flags.

Comment: I know that global variables are stored in data segment while local ones are usually on stack segment. I'm not sure about where the pointer variables and the constant variables are stored, and is for loop stored in text segment?

Answer (score 1):

GCC would store constants in the text section.